# Lighter bike for climbing

Tags: road-bike, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the effect of adding weight to a wheel vs adding it to the frame?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7428/what-is-the-effect-of-adding-weight-to-a-wheel-vs-adding-it-to-the-frame)

Do lighter wheels make a significant difference when climbing or would a lighter frame do the same? Do lighter inner-tubes and tyres make the same difference?

Comment: Very similar to this question http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7428/what-is-the-effect-of-adding-weight-to-a-wheel-vs-adding-it-to-the-frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of climbing at a steady speed, weight on the wheel is exactly the same as weight on the saddle.

In terms of acceleration, weight at the rim slows acceleration (but also deceleration) by 2x of the same weight on the saddle.